# Why does my voice over sound like it's been reduced in quality when I Compress it?

Tags: audacity, voice, compression, voice-over

I'm recording audio for a video essay with Audacity and a Blue Yeti microphone. The microphone is held by a stand and it's got a pop filter.

I've watched a few YouTube tutorials like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYF5ytMDFpA) on what kinds of post-processing should be done on an audio file to increase its quality. These tutorials usually detail 6 steps:

1. Reduce the noise profile
2. Compress the audio track
3. Boost the Bass
4. Boost the Treble
5. Add a Limiter
6. Normalize

However, when I Compress my audio recording, it makes the audio sound cheaper. While the Playback Level of the untouched recording averages around -12, post-compression it increases past 0. The audio sounds like it's been reduced from a high quality recording from a decent mic, to the default microphone on a laptop, with noticeable amounts of distortion unless it's played on a very low volume.

I'm relatively new to this, but understand that Compression should balance the audio out. Am I doing something wrong when I try to edit the track with Audacity, or is this something more on the physical recording end?

Comment: this really depends on the settings you're using for steps 2-5.

Comment: Suggest you post a before and after audio clip and we may be able to tell you what you are doing wrong.